How to enable PUT Method in Tomcat for a context (simple web application)
This question has been asked in various forms for last 13 years that I could track and never been adequately answered for a simple web app context.

The CORS Filter Solution
The Servlet Solution
The Incomplete Solution
The Spring No Answer/Only Comment Solution

The solution that works as of Tomcat 9.0.x is as follows
Tomcat by default covers any HTTP methods apart from GET and POST from access. First, PUT needs to be uncovered. This can be done with a security constraint that does not disallow PUT method (exclude PUT from the security-constraint).
In web.xml declare a security constraint with an empty auth-constraint excluding PUT. An empty auth-constraint means no constraint will ever match it (note: an empty auth-constraint explicitly means there is no auth constraint at all). Mapping it to '/*' will allow PUT for all URL patterns.
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restricted Methods</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>PATCH</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>

Next, Tomcat has a servlet configured in conf/web.xml (which gets loaded for all web applications be default) that has the DefaultServlet configured that handles all requests that don't match any other servlet configured in web app context web.xml. This servlet is by default configured to disallow any write operations on context, e.g. PUT and DELETE. This servlet needs to be configured to allow write operations (it is an extremely bad idea to do this but for now live with it).
To enable write operations, this servlet needs to be configured with an init param 'readonly' set to false. This can be done as follows
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>readonly</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

Once the above two aspects are configured. Tomcat will accept PUT request (for ALL CONTEXTS, with the grace of by being covered by default for other contexts*).
This matter needs to be addressed, such that PUT is only enabled for the current context and not any other contexts in the server.
This can be done by declaring the DefaultServlet (with readonly --> false) in the web.xml of the context that needs PUT request and setting readonly--> true in the conf/web.xml
<web-app version="4.0" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
    
    <display-name>Swagger UI</display-name>
    <description>Swagger UI</description>    
    
    <!-- Below methods are restricted across the site, unsafe methods are masked -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Restricted Methods</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>PATCH</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>readonly</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
</web-app>

